# How to select a row where a given quantity falls within a tier or range?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Say you have a table matching a price per unit to a range or tier of quantities:

| Quantity | Price Per Unit | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $50 | Applies to qtys 1-9 |
| 10 | $25 | Applies to qtys 10-49 |
| 50 | $15 | Applies to qtys 50-99 |
| 100 | $10 | Applies to qtys 100+ |

For example, the price per unit $50 would apply to item quantities 1-9. If there are 10 items, the price becomes $25 per unit, until 49, then for anything between 50 and 99, the price is $15, and anything 100+ is $10 per item.

How would you SELECT the correct row for any given quantity, such that only 1 row is returned for a given quantity? For example:

- Quantity 1 -> $50
- Quantity 2 -> $50
- Quantity 12 -> $25
- etc.

```
    SET @qty := 12;
    SELECT
        quantity,
        pricePerUnit
    FROM
        prices
    WHERE
        quantity <= @qty; -- doesn't work, returns rows for both 1 and 10
```

Comment: You probably wouldn't structure your data in this way. You'd have a minimum quantity field to determine your price breaks instead of a text field. But generally you just need to select top 1 (limit your result set to the first matching row)

Comment: @Charleh thank you for your insights. What would be a better table schema? Adding MinQty and MaxQty columns?

Comment: You only need `Min Quantity` - someone already answered with the same concept

Comment: Whoever downvoted, why don't you specify what's amiss with the question?

Answer (score 3):

here is how you can do it by sorting them and fetch only one row:

```
    SET @qty := 12;
    SELECT
        quantity,
        pricePerUnit
    FROM prices
    WHERE quantity <= @qty
    order by quantity desc
    limit 1
```